# How can I set line stretch inside lstlistings for displaying code?

Tags: listings, latex3

I have a long document and I set a different spacing like this:

```
\usepackage{setspace}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
```

This stretching also applies inside my lstlisting, but I would like to have a different spacing only inside the snippets WITHOUT setting the spacing before and after the listing, e.g.

```
\setstretch{1.0} %  this is not cool
\begin{lstlisting}
...
\end{lstlisting}
\setstretch{1.5} % this is not cool
```

These are my settings for my lstlistings

```
\lstset{
  setstretching=1.0, % Is there somethign like this???
  frame=shadowbox,
  rulesepcolor=\color{blue!50},
  numbers=left,
  language=C++,
  aboveskip=3mm,
  backgroundcolor=\color{blue!10},
  belowskip=3mm,
  showstringspaces=false,
  columns=flexible,
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  numbers=none,
  numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},
  commentstyle=\small\color{dkgreen},
  stringstyle=\color{mauve},
  breaklines=true,
  breakatwhitespace=true,
  tabsize=3
}
```